# Remove Successful login information from SQL Server Log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, audit-logging

I want to use Audit Log to store successful/failed login info and remove the same from SQL Server Log. This way I can segregate the information in a different log file and increase the readability of both log files (SQL Server Log and Audit Log file).

I know how to enable both information in Audit but didn't find anything to remove login information from SQL Log.

Comment: This one should definitely go to [DBA Stack](https://dba.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

It's in the Server Properties under security.

[image: Example]

I needed to restart SQL Engine to get this to take effect.